# DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java

I am trying to use OracleConnection.DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS but it's showing an error as below:
DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS cannot be resolved or is not a field

I am using ojdbc6.jar & JDK1.7 & using below import statements:
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver;

Eclipse is being used as IDE.

what could be the reason?

Comment: There is no issue with the external Jar. When i tried the same piece of code in different project with the same external jar. It worked. But for the current project, I have tried cleaning up the project, still, issue persist.

Comment: Issue is found. There was another jar for same purpose (but didn't have DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS) which led to conflict. Once the extra jar was removed, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is found. There was another jar (class12.jar) for similar purpose (but didn't have DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS) which led to conflict. Once that jar was removed, it worked fine.